# Underscore.js, why does `isFunction` use `|| false`?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The optional override for `isFunction(object)` in Underscore.js ([repo link to definition](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1312)), reads as follows:

```
// Optimize `isFunction` if appropriate. Work around some typeof bugs in old v8,
// IE 11 (#1621), Safari 8 (#1929), and PhantomJS (#2236).
var nodelist = root.document && root.document.childNodes;
if (typeof /./ != 'function' && typeof Int8Array != 'object' && typeof nodelist != 'function') {
    _.isFunction = function(obj) {
        return typeof obj == 'function' || false;
    };
}
```

What I'm confused about is the `|| false`, why is it necessary after a string comparison? Since [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) always returns a string there should be no ambiguity?
The comment states the override fixes some `typeof` bugs, are there cases on the listed platforms when `typeof` doesn't return a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the issues covered in the comments, [#1621](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1621), [#1929](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1929) and [#2236](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2236).

Shortly put, some platforms have a bug where `typeof` isn't a string unless you store it in a variable.
The `|| false` fixes the issue without introducing an extra variable.

Taken directly from [#1621](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1621):

In IE8, with a variable everything works as expected:

```
var t = typeof obj
t === 'function' // false
t === 'object' // true
```

but without one, things are different:

```
(typeof obj) === 'function' // true, but SHOULD be false
(typeof obj) === 'object' // true
```

The extra check outlined above fixes the bug.